# Unique key having length of 8

Tags: c#

I have to generate the unique key having a length of 8, which should be comprised of some set of characters:

> ```
> {B,C,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,X,Y,Z,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
> ```

Now I have written a program that will generate it, but I am not sure it will generate the unique key.  Could you please review it?.

```
static string[]  unicode = {"66","67","68","70","71","72","74","75","76","77","78","80","81","82","83","84","86","87","88","89","90","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57"};
```

These are the ASCII representation of above character:

```
long k=5050505050505050; // this initially starts from 5050505050505050

List<string> lst=new List<string>();
void Main(){ 
    while(lst.Count()<1000000 && k!=9090909090909090)
    {

        var NoSet=Split(k.ToString(),2);

        if(NoSet.Count()==8){

            var no=string.Join("",NoSet.Select(x=>(char)(Convert.ToInt32(x))));
            lst.Add(no);

        }

        k++;
    }
}
```

Finally, store the last value of K variable to generate the next 1000000 unique key:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize){
return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
    .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize)).Where(x=>unicode.Contains(x)).Select(x=>x);}
```

Output from the list:

> 22222222
>
> 22222223
>
> 22222224
>
> 22222225
>
> 22222226
>
> 22222227
>
> 22222228
>
> 22222229
>
> 2222222B
>
> 2222222C
>
> 2222222D

Comment: Why an 8 character set? This problem has been solved in the way of GUIDs already. (Granted, they're larger and not 100% guaranteed of being unique, but I promise you it's a better solution than rolling your own.)

Comment: Thanks @ckuhn203 but we have a business requirement cause key should be human readable and memorable you can assume it like a batch no of product.

Answer (score 6):

It looks from the data as if you do not need the numbers to be random, only unique. 
A solution is to take the numbers from 1 to 1,000,000 but output them in base 29 using the allowed characters.

```
private static readonly char[] Values = {
        'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '2',
        '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
    };

private static readonly int ValueCount = Values.Length;

private IEnumerable<string> GenerateValues(int count) {
    for (var c = 0; c < count; c++) {
        yield return FormatNumber(c);
    }
}

private static string FormatNumber(int value) {

    var digits = new[] { Values[0], Values[0], Values[0], Values[0], Values[0], Values[0], Values[0], Values[0] };
    var slotCount = digits.Length;

    var current = value;
    var count = 0;
    while (current > 0) {
        int rem;
        current = Math.DivRem(current, ValueCount, out rem);
        digits[slotCount - ++count] = Values[rem];
    }

    return new string(digits);
}
```

This will generate:

```
BBBBBBBB  (0)
BBBBBBBC  (1)
BBBBBBBD  (2)
...
BBBCQBC3  (1,000,000)
```

you can modify it to start at any point and to generate different amount of Ids (up to \$29^8-1\$)

Comment: Loving the readability/simplicity of this solution.

Comment: @AlanT can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74929129/sequential-alphanumeric-string-generation-with-2-alpha-and-7-numeric-digits ,